# How to inject Symfony form extension?

Tags: forms, symfony, configuration

I want to make extension to Symfony forms. This is not Symfony **Type** extension. How to register my custom extension in symfony config (as a service maybe?)

Examples already in Symfony are:

```
Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\DoctrineOrmExtension 
Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\HttpFoundation\HttpFoundationExtension
```

According to [this](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/reference/dic_tags.html) only available tags are:

```
form.type
form.type_extension
form.type_guesser
```

There is no `form.extension` that i need

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's true there is no **form.extension** tag in symfony2 and those extensions are not even being  registered in the container as services using a tag or event. ( actually they aren't even used ... )

Just register a service tagged **form.type_extension** and add your extension to the builder in the `buildForm()` method.

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addExtension(new YourWhateverExtension());
}
```

This is how they are added registered manually.

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\HttpFoundation\HttpFoundationExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Csrf\CsrfExtension;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Csrf\CsrfProvider\SessionCsrfProvider;

$session = new Session();
$secret = 'V8a5Z97e...';
$formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
    ->addExtension(new HttpFoundationExtension())
    ->addExtension(new CsrfExtension(new SessionCsrfProvider($session, $secret)))
    ->getFormFactory();
```

Symfony uses the factory service **@form.factory**.

The @form.factory declaration can be found [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/form.xml#L35).

Digging deeper you will find **@form.registry** service [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/form.xml#L20)

```
    <!-- FormRegistry -->
    <service id="form.registry" class="%form.registry.class%">
        <argument type="collection">
            <!--
            We don't need to be able to add more extensions.
             * more types can be registered with the form.type tag
             * more type extensions can be registered with the form.type_extension tag
             * more type_guessers can be registered with the form.type.type_guesser tag
            -->
            <argument type="service" id="form.extension" />
        </argument>
        <argument type="service" id="form.resolved_type_factory" />
    </service>
```

---

**tip:**

You can debug container tags in symfony2 using the `app/console container:debug` command since 2.2 - see [this PR](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/4937).

**List all tags using**

```
app/console container:debug --tags
```

**Search for a certain tag using**

```
app/console container:debug --tag=form.type_guesser --show-private
```